# How to solve system of nonlinear differeintial equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

**System follows:**
$$ y'=\frac{y^2}{z-x};  
z'=y+1$$

I was found the 2 ways. The both are wrong

1) $$z = x + \frac{y^2}{y'};  z'=1+\frac{2yy'^2-y^2y''}{y'^2}=y+1; => (p(y) = y')=> yp(yp'+p)=0;$$
$$ y=0, y' = \frac{c}{y}<=>y=C e^{\frac{c}{y}}$$ 
it looks like an answer, but there is must be x instead y in power of e.

**There was my fault**
$$ yp'-p=0; \frac{p'}{p}=\frac{1}{y}; p=cy=y'; \frac{dy}{y}=c dx; y=C e^{cx};$$
$$ z'=C e^{cx} + 1; z = \frac{C}{c} e^{cx} + x + const$$
There was not enough persistence of myself.
Thanks for **Mike**

**Answer is**
$$y=C e^{cx}; z = \frac{C}{c} e^{cx} + x + const$$

---

2) 
$$y=z'-1, y'=z''$$
$$(z-x)z''=(z'-1)^2$$
$$x=e^t, z=ue^{mt}, (m-1)=0$$
$$z'=(u+u'), z'' = e^{-t}(u'+u'')$$
$$ p(u)=u', pp'=u''$$
$$(u-1)(p+pp')=(u-1+p)^2$$
$$p'-1=\frac{u-1}{p}+\frac{p}{u-1}$$
I stuck here...

**A search for my fault of the second way is open**

PS: tag Филипов решение 1142

Comment: What is the independent variable?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since no one else has responded, I'll try taking a stab at it.  Let me try reworking your first attempt from here

$$2yy'^2-y^2y''=yy'^2$$
$$yy'^2-y^2y''=0$$

I feel I'm missing something simple here, but I'll try your substitution

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=p$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=p'p$$
$$yp^2-y^2pp'=yp(p-yp')=0$$

This seems to leave 3 possibilities.  $p=0$ does not appear to work.  It may have been introduced when the derivative of $z$ was taken.  $y=0$ yields $z=x+k$.  The last possibility is

$$yp'-p=0$$
$$\frac{p'}y-\frac p{y^2}=0$$
$$\frac py=k,p=\frac{dy}{dx}=ky$$
$$\ln y=kx+c,y=k_2e^{kx}$$
$$z'=k_2e^{kx}+1$$
$$z=\frac{k_2}ke^{kx}+x+k_3$$

Trying this back in the first equation, we have

$$\frac{y^2}{z-x}=\frac{k_2^2e^{2kx}}{\frac{k_2}ke^{kx}+k_3}$$

Again, it looks like extra solutions may have been introduced.  However, with the restriction $k_3=0$, we have

$$\frac{k_2^2e^{2kx}}{\frac{k_2}ke^{kx}}=kk_2e^{kx}=y'$$

Comment: Thank you. You have made a very interesting trick with the equation $yp'-p=0$. It is a homogeneous equation, where it is easy to get an answer p(y). Where you get the idea of evaluate a ratio to a constant k? Can you explain me by words your logic?

Comment: @so-olitary If I understand the question, I guessed that taking the derivative may have introduced extra solutions, so I simply checked the solutions to make sure they worked.  For example, $p=0$ led to $y=C$.  But the only way to make that fraction $0$ was if $C=0$.  For the last case, the solution only checked if $k_3=0$.

Comment: My question was about ratio p/y=k. You have divided an equation by y^2, and then you write this ratio. What were your considerations to do it? My logic is different, you can see above.

Comment: @so-olitary Ah, that.  I saw the integrating factor by sight.  Multiplying by the correct integrating factor should transform one side of the equation into $(f(x)y)'$.  In general, for the equation $y'+f(x)y=g(x)$, the integrating factor is $e^{\int f(x)dx}$.  In this case, $e^{\int-\frac1ydy}=e^{-\ln y}=e^{\ln\frac1y}=\frac1y$